# PyDev debugger different from command line django runserver command

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I am trying to debug a problem with a django view. When I run it on the command line.
I don't get any of these messages. However when I run the it in the PyDev debugger i get these error messages. I am running with the **--noreload** option.

What do these error messages mean?

Why do I not get them when I run it on the command line?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/threading.py:697: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
  return _active[_get_ident()]
Exception exceptions.SystemError: 'error return without exception set' in <generator object at 0x786c10> ignored
Exception exceptions.SystemError: 'error return without exception set' in <generator object at 0x7904e0> ignored
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall having similar issues debugging in PyDev related to the auto-reload mechanism of Django's test server.  You can turn reloading off by passing --noreload to your runserver command.  From there you just have to train yourself to restart your test server after making a code change while debugging.

**EDIT**

It's been a while since I used PyDev together with Django, but I do recall there being some warning messages spit out to the console that didn't affect my ability to debug. There are quite a few message board posts related to that message in debugging other Python libraries, but I didn't find any that have a resolution.

I guess it is benign as long as you can ignore it and still debug your code.  I don't think you need to be concerned that it's a problem with your application code, but something deep down in PyDev or the Python debugging facilities.

Comment: Yeah I am running with the --noreload option.